# Interface unboxing for complex Types

Tags: c#, .net

I have a interface with some classes. To easy describe my task:

```
IAnimal
 Cat
 Dog
 Ape
 ..
```

now, in Program.cs, i fill a list of objects

```
 List<IAnimal> animals = new..
 animals.Add(new Cat {})
 animals.Add(new Ape {})
 ...
```

With this done, 
I want some action to the objects.

```
 animals.ForEach(a => doSomething(a));
```

What I want to do, depends on what type coming up.

```
void doSomething(IAnimal animal)
{
    switch (animal.GetType().Name)
    {
        case "Dog":
            parseDog(); // parts of a dog?
            break;
            ...
    }
}
```

My question, as final, is if I can make this more nice then this textual identification and switch method. Like putting a generic T in the interface, better typeof-use or something else?

Thank's in advanced

Comment: Not sure an interface is the best choice for this...

Comment: I'm not sure if this sample corresponds fully to the reality, please hit me with your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an example of "the wrong abstraction" and a violation of [Liskov Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  If your `doSomething()` method has a dependency on the specific implementation of `IAnimal` being passed to it, then the `IAnimal` interface isn't really abstracting it properly.  The method shouldn't care what implementation it gets, because for its purposes it should need only what's on `IAnimal`.

Can your "parse" method just be added to `IAnimal` such that, rather than a `switch` on implementations, you just call `animal.Parse()` and allow each implementation to handle that accordingly?  If only a `Dog` has a meaningful implementation for that method, then the others can just have empty methods or throw a `NotImplementedException` or however you want to handle it.

Comment: Thank's David. I'm very much into a violation of the LSP and have refactored some code of this specific part today. Which ended up in a better abstraction and - as you mentioned - no switch or if descision at all.

Answer (score 4):

You are re-inventing virtual methods.  The slow way.  It is automatic with an interface, add a Parse() method.  Now it is simple:

```
void doSomething(IAnimal animal)
{
    animal.Parse();
}
```

It probably ought to have an argument...

Comment: Thank's. I haven't mind that we had a Parse() on interface objects,

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
void doSomething(IAnimal animal)
{
    if (animal is Dog)
    {
        parseDog(); // parts of a dog?
    }
    else if (animal is Cat)
    {
        parseCat();
    }
    else if (animal is Ape)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But anyway, it's probably not the best approach... you should make `DoSomething` a method of `IAnimal`, and implement it in each `IAnimal` implementation

Comment: Your probably right about that and Hans/David camed with interesting fact there. I will run back into this tomorrow,

Answer (score 1):

Hey Jonas, if you have an interface do define IAnimal, why dont you define a method which is gonna handle this type-specific behavior??? Actually this is the best way, and youll be using polimorphism for it! Take a look;

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    void Move();
}

public class Bird : IAnimal
{
    public void Move()
    {
        //Realize that this is a type-specific behavior,
        //which could be different for each class that
        //implements IAnimal, NO NEED FOR UNBOXING
        //or a bunch of IFS!!!
        Console.WriteLine("Im flying!");
    }
}

public class Horse : IAnimal
{
    public void Move()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Im running!");
    }
}


//Then you may use it this way;
listOfIAnimals.ForEach(c => c.Move());
```

If you still wanna make the comparison the best way is using the "IS" keyword!

if(Bird is IAnimal), etc...!

Comment: Thank's Renato. That's true and partly an answer **if(Bird Is IAnimal)**. Partly because David and Hans camed with interesting approaches which I will going through tomorrow (GMT+1CEST).

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to do with the Type, just how you do, but in cases put typeof(Dog|Cat|...)